# Eliminando valores jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un duda utilizando jQuery, tengo que eliminar el texto que va a continuación de cada input de name = 'item' para sustituir luego cada palabra que inserte del textarea en cada input...

```
<div id="capa">

        <form name="formulario">
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <input type="button" value="Ver palabras"><br>  <br>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="todos">Seleccionar todos
            <input type="checkbox" id="ninguno">Deseleccionar todos
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="1">Esto
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="2">es
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="3">un
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="4">texto
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="5">de
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="6">prueba
            <br>                


        </form>
    </div>
```

Y aquí mi código JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click',function() {
        var valoresTextArea = $('textarea').val();
        //Utilizando los espacios en blanco separo cada palabra y la almaceno en cada posicion de un array
        var palabras =  valoresTextArea.split(" ");
        //Almaceno todos los input
        var inputs = $("input[name='item']");

        inputs.after().remove();


    });
```

Lo intento eliminar con remove() utilizando after para que borre lo que va después del input que es el texto que quiero eliminar, pero no lo elimina... ¿alguna recomendación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo la solución para ti:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click',function() {
        var valoresTextArea = $('textarea').val();
        //Utilizando los espacios en blanco separo cada palabra y la almaceno en cada posicion de un array
        var palabras =  valoresTextArea.split(" ");
        //Almaceno todos los input
        var inputs = $("input[name='item']");

        for(let check of inputs){
            check.nextSibling.remove()
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="capa">

        <form name="formulario">
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <input type="button" value="Ver palabras"><br>  <br>  
            <input type="checkbox" id="todos">Seleccionar todos
            <input type="checkbox" id="ninguno">Deseleccionar todos
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="1">Esto
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="2">es
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="3">un
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="4">texto
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="5">de
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item" value="6">prueba
            <br>                


        </form>
    </div>
```

Lo que he hecho es recorrer cada uno de los `checks`, coger a su siguiente hermano, en nuestro caso el texto, `nextSibling` y eliminarlo. Creo que no se puede hacer lo que tu intentabas. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muy bien, ha sido una aportación fantastica. Ahora si que hace lo que pretendo. Muy util.